# Is the gap between the sheathing and header on this wall functional?

Tags: insulation, exterior, ventilation

I am insulating my garage. This exterior wall's sheathing stops a few inches from the header. The gray strip is metal flashing. Exterior to that is Vinyl siding. Does stopping the sheathing below the header serve some purpose, perhaps for ventilation? It's all very well weatherproofed, there are no current leaks or issues. Most importantly, to finish this wall can I simply install batts of insulation in the bays and seal them with sheathing? Thanks.

[image: Exterior garage wall from inside. Gray strip is flashing.]

Answer (score 2):

The plywood for structural sake should be covering up to the top plate. In this case, I think is is either a matter of laziness on the original builders part, or lack of materials.

IMO, insulate and carry on.

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but it's possible the sheathing pieces are exactly 48" long...now why could that be...LOL. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: With the grain running in the direction it is it should be the 8' height, unless it is a very short garage wall, and the sheets were ripped in half? If that is the case, it would have meant a lot of waste, or a lot of time adding blocking in behind all the horizontal joints.